# Получение сторонних данных из LocalStorage

Tags: javascript, python, golang, localstorage, cors

Друзья!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как я могу получить эти данные из LocalStorage. Есть проект, есть код, который ищет фильмы по ID и выводит их через Alloha.TV в мой проект(iframe). При просмотре фильма, а далее последующим обновлением страницы, данные эпизода, времени просмотра сохраняются в LocalStorage, который приходит от домена: https://sansa.newplayjj.com:9443. Все данные хранятся там, ниже приложу пример скриншота. Обычными методами получение значений по ключу невозможно получить значение, и как-то его сохранить, т.к. выводится null. Скажите, пожалуйста, как все-таки можно получить эти данные? Python или GO, например, если не говорить уже о JavaScript. Плееры эти работают на PlayerJS. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Чтобы попробовать у себя код:

```js
new Kinobox(".kinobox_player", {
    search: {
        kinopoisk: "460586",
    },
    players: {},
}).init();
```

```css
iframe {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="kinobox_player"></div>
<script src="https://kinobox.tv/kinobox.min.js"></script>
```